# Javascript - Is there a way to revoke appendChild without removing the child node?

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I have a drag and drop function in the javascript game that I am creating at the moment.
I've given it a condition to listen to, if it meets the condition, the game will progress to next stage. (If number image matches given condition and fruit image given matches the condition, allow to drop, and reload the number image with next one.)
And these images are all stored in arrays. So to display them, I'm setting the background image of the div.

The problem is that the fruit image appended will remain in the same position. I have tried using removeChild() but removes the whole div. Also tried creating a new div to replace the removed div. It does create a new div but it remains on where it is dropped.

Is there a way to undo the appendChild?

```js
function createDiv() {
    var newDiv = '<div id="fruit2" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragend="dragEnd(event)"></div>';
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("fruitCloud2");
    parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
}

function stage2() {
    createDiv();
    
    document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + numberAddress + myNumber[1] + ")";
    document.getElementById("fruit1").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fruit1Address + fruitCloudOne[randFruit1] + ")";
    document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[randFruit2] + ")";
    document.getElementById("fruit3").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + fruit3Address + fruitCloudThree[randFruit3] + ")";
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragStart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("fruit", ev.target.id);
}

function onDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  
  if (document.getElementById("number").style.backgroundImage == 'url("' + numberAddress + myNumber[0] +'")' && document.getElementById("fruit2").style.backgroundImage == 'url("' + fruit2Address + fruitCloudTwo[0] + '")') {
      var dropSource = ev.dataTransfer.getData("fruit");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(dropSource));
      stage2();
      ev.target.removeChild(document.getElementById(dropSource));
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

#background {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(Assets/Background_cloudPosition.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0%;
    z-index: -10;
}

#startGame {
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: green;
}

#refreshFruits {
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#number {
    position: absolute;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    left: 450px;
    bottom: 415px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 15;
}

#fruitCloud1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    bottom: 460px;
    left: 135px;
    z-index: 15;
}

#fruitCloud2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    bottom: 320px;
    left: 300px;
    z-index: 15;
}

#fruitCloud3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    bottom: 185px;
    left: 110px;
    z-index: 15;
}

#fruit1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#fruit2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#fruit3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 120px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#jelly {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(Assets/JellyMonster/JellyMonsterDefault.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 260px;
    height: 190px;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 390px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<html>
    
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    <title>This is an experiment.</title>
    
</head>
    
<body>
<!--- --->
<button id="download" onclick="download()"></button>
    
<button id="startGame" onclick="startGame()"></button>
<button id="refreshFruits" onclick="refreshFruits()"></button>

<div id="number"></div>
    
<div id="jelly" ondrop="onDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>

<div class="fruit" id="fruitCloud1">
    <div id="fruit1" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragend="dragEnd(event)"></div>
</div>

<div class="fruit" id="fruitCloud2">
    <div id="fruit2" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragend="dragEnd(event)"></div>
</div>
    
<div class="fruit" id="fruitCloud3">
    <div id="fruit3" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragend="dragEnd(event)"></div>
</div>

</body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to this myself.
Instead of removing child (dropsource), I set visibility to hidden.
Then on the next stage function, I set it back to visible and appended the fruit div back to its parent div, which is the div with id fruitcloud.